# How to use Magento API Soap Web services in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, magento, jquery, cordova

Am using PhoneGap for iOS development. Am trying to call [Magento API With the SOAP Web services](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) in PhoneGap. My scenario is i want to send the username and apikey to the Webservice. Since its a client based with the help of jQuery-Ajax and javascript i tried to send the data to web service but got failed.

When i tried with Jquery-Ajax i got an XML parsing error states '0' as error message(Cros Domain problem). In Javascript i can get the response correctly but dont know how to send the username and apikey to the web service, Below is the script code i used,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create the XHR object.

  function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
       // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
       xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
      // XDomainRequest for IE.
         xhr = new XDomainRequest();
         xhr.open(method, url);
      } else {
     // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
   }return xhr;

// Make the actual CORS request.

function makeCorsRequest() {
   // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
   var url = 'my WSDL link for magento api';
   var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
   if (!xhr) {
      alert('CORS not supported');
   return;}
   // Response handlers.
   xhr.onload = function() {
   var text = xhr.responseText;
      alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url);
   };
   xhr.onerror = function() {
      alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
   };
  xhr.send();
}
</script>
```

Here i don't know how to send the username and apikey to this Soap Web service.

Can anyone suggest me

- how to send the username and apikey to the soap web service?
- Is there any alternative way to send data to soap web service using Client side programming?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no need to avoid the cross-domain problem of jquery.

1.A simple 'jsonp' will help you solve your question.
2.You may modify the head of response in server-side.
Please refer to my c# code below:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Comment: I tried with the `*` code already still my problem exists. Will jsonp supports in phonegap?

Comment: Jsonp supports jquery. I have used it to solve cross-domain problem for times.